# Integral over a square

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to integrate  $f(z)= 1/ (z \bar{z})$   over a square centered at the origin oriented counter clockwise. I know this function is holomorphic except at $(0,0)$ My teacher says this integral is equivalent if i integrate $f(z)$ over a circle centered at $(0,0)$  oriented counter clockwise that is contained in the square.

Can someone explain why this is true?
Thanks
J.M.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this function is absolutely not holomorphic. (Because of the $\overline{z}$).

Comment: Are you talking about a "line" integral like $\int_C \frac{dz}{z\bar{z}}$ where $C$ is either a circle $\{ z: |z| = 1 \}$ or a square $\{ z : \max\{ |\Re z|, |\Im z| \} = 1 \}$ or a "surface" integral? In the first case, both integrals vanish because under the map $z \to -z$, the integrand $\frac{1}{z\bar{z}}$ and $C$ are both invariant  while $dz$ picks up a minus sign.

Comment: C is a circle, but i dont understand your explanation.

Comment: @achillehui can u help me?

Comment: Please, write using standard english: "u" is not.